# MYSQL based FulltextSearchable With Elemental blocks

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

Is it possible to use the mysql based fulltextsearchable functionality to search elemental blocks content?

Elemental has integration features with Solr, but I'm working on a few sites that are too small to justify running a server instance for search.

Answer (score 1):

The `DNADesign\Elemental\Extensions\ElementalPageExtension` provides a `getElementsForSearch()` method which is the elemental blocks concatenated and includes some configuration to customise it.

For this to work in a database-based search you'll need to store that (or something like it but why re-invent the wheel?) in the database. You can do this by declaring a new db field on the page and then using something like `onBeforeWrite()` on the page to actually store the data.

Be aware that you can save and publish blocks separately to the page though, which will complicate matters somewhat and could lead to stale data depending on how you handle this.

Comment: thanks.  this would be a good starting point but i was hoping for there to be a more out-of-the-box solution for such a basic function

Comment: @Will agreed. I used to use https://addons.silverstripe.org/add-ons/jbennecker/silverstripe-elemental-site-search for this but isn't updated to SS5. Scroll tot the bottom https://github.com/dnadesign/silverstripe-elemental-textcontentforsearch and see the ToDo...

Answer (score 0):

Yes MySql full text search is efficient and reliable, just concatenate your blocks in a text column separated by spaces and index this column.

Avoiding using a search server like Solr should save you lots of pain.

Comment: Concatenate my bocks in a text column how? by extending elemental?  @laurent PELE - is your comment silverstripe specific or just a general observation?

Comment: This sounds like it's basically the same as what I suggested - the output of the `getElementsForSearch()` method is the concatenated set of elemental content for any given page.